# Change gc.auto Parameter

Tags: git

I would to change gc.auto parameter to something "much larger than 6700" as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633981/what-does-auto-packing-the-repository-for-optimum-) so git `gc --auto` does not run every time I do a  pull (which it is doing now for some reason) how do I do this? I have checked the config file and do not see this parameter should I add it? I have run `git gc --aggressive` twice and `git gc --auto` is still running on every pull.

performance-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the git config command:

```
git config --global gc.auto 13400
```

That will double the parameter size for all your repos. As a note setting it to 0 disables it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to add it from the command line in the repository that requires adjustment:

```
git config --local gc.auto <value>
```

where `<value>` is the number that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add a new config option.

- If you want the config to be local to your repo, run this:

  ```
  git config --local gc.auto <NEW_VALUE>
  ```
- If you want it to be global, use this:

  ```
  git config --global gc.auto <NEW_VALUE>
  ```
- You could also add the following lines manually to your `~/.gitconfig` or your repo's `.git/config`:

  ```
  [gc]
      auto = NEW_VALUE
  ```