# How can I hide "Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance" meesages?

Tags: git

Sometimes git shows me

```
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
```

this just distracts me from whatever I am doing and initially worries me that something may be wrong.

How I can tell git to shut up about this until I need to take action?

Why it is even being shown?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233094/11404396

Comment: It disables entire feature, not just the message. "uninstall git" also technically solves the issue

Comment: My apologies, I had misread the linked comment.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers in the question that LR linked to in the comments have the kind of information you seem to be looking for, but I'm very interested in git, so I am going to answer you directly here because of that curiousity.

From the git-scm.org website, the `git` `gc` is the git "garbage collector".  There is great enough [documentation on the garbage collector](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) on the git-scm.org website.

I have not really personally poked around the source code to know exactly, but it seems the git garbage collector is a git feature occasionally triggered as part of other git feature commands such as 'git fetch' that cleans up the git-managed repository files on the local file system.  That necessary because it is easily possible to use git in such a way that versions of files are cached on the local file system but are no longer used by anything and therefore are garbage collectible.

`git reset --hard` is one situation that can result in an unreferenced commit that is no longer needed and therefore could be deleted by the git gc.  The gc docs describe other things too like compressing repository managed data files to conserve disk usage.  You can run the gc feature with the simple `git gc` though the documentation describes that as normally unnecessary.

Concerning the distracting console message, IMO that specific message should not be a bother even if unexpected.  The git-scm.org website page describes the option `git gc --quiet` as something that might be what you are looking for, but because there is no matching 'git gc --quiet-off' or 'git gc --loud' and there is no git config setting related to gc verbosity, it looks like from the git version 2.44.0 documentation and my quick v. 2.43.2 testing the message might be unavoidable.  LR's comment suggestion might be really what you want, especially if you're not dealing with big files.

Other system configurations and specific git implementations should not cause different results, but that is a possibility.